# Unable to open sqlite database file when program launch at windows startup

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, windows-10, startup

I set my program to launch at startup by the below code:

```
Registry.CurrentUser
    .OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true)
    .SetValue(Application.ProductName, Application.ExecutablePath);
```

After restarting Windows and login to my account (with admin access), the program runs successfully, but when it tries to connect to the sqlite file, it encounters the following exception:

```
"ClassName": "System.Data.DataException",
  "Message": "An exception occurred while initializing the database. See the InnerException for details.",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": {
    "ClassName": "System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException",
    "Message": "The underlying provider failed on Open.",
    "Data": null,
    "InnerException": {
      "errorCode": 14,
      "ClassName": "System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException",
      "Message": "unable to open database file",
      "Data": null,
      "InnerException": null,
      "HelpURL": null,
      "StackTraceString": "
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLite3.Open(String strFilename, String vfsName, SQLiteConnectionFlags connectionFlags, SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum openFlags, Int32 maxPoolSize, Boolean usePool)
   at System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<>c.<Open>b__13_0(DbConnection t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext](TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<Open>b__55_0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()",
      "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
      "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
      "ExceptionMethod": "8\nOpen\nSystem.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.113.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139\nSystem.Data.SQLite.SQLite3\nVoid Open(System.String, System.String, System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnectionFlags, System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteOpenFlagsEnum, Int32, Boolean)",
      "HResult": -2147481601,
      "Source": "System.Data.SQLite",
      "WatsonBuckets": null
    },
    "HelpURL": null,
    "StackTraceString": "
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection(Boolean shouldMonitorTransactions)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass174_0.<ExecuteStoreCommand>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String commandText, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior transactionalBehavior, String sql, Object[] parameters)
   at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Create(Database db, DbModel model)
   at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteInitializerBase`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at SQLite.CodeFirst.SqliteCreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.<>c__DisplayClass66_0`1.<CreateInitializationAction>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)",
    "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
    "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
    "ExceptionMethod": "8\nOpen\nEntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection\nVoid Open()",
    "HResult": -2146233087,
    "Source": "EntityFramework",
    "WatsonBuckets": null
  },
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": "
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.<>c.<InitializeDatabase>b__58_0(InternalContext c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at Watcher.MainApplication..ctor()
   at Watcher.Program.Main()",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": "8\nPerformInitializationAction\nEntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext\nVoid PerformInitializationAction(System.Action)",
  "HResult": -2146233087,
  "Source": "EntityFramework",
  "WatsonBuckets": null
```

This problem disappears when I run the program manually

I tried to use a text file instead of a database, but a file created by a program run by Windows is different from a file created by a program run manually.

How can I solve this problem on windows 10?

Comment: That's not an exception, that's a message. Post the *full exception text*. Not just the name, message or stack trace. Post the full string returned by `Exception.ToString()`. The account that runs the application may not have permission to read the SQLite file. What account does that application run in? Hint: it's not any logged-on user

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I updated the post and I emphasize again that there is no error when running the program manually and this problem only occurs when Windows runs the program at startup

Comment: Again, what account is running that application on startup, when no-one is logged? It's not *your* account.

Comment: I guess Windows will move the program to another location like a sandbox and try to run the program from there

Comment: After logging in to my account, which I am the administrator, it runs the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I restart and run in the startup case, the current directory is the systems directory.

So to fix this I need to use the full path.